# Apache - file not send with UTF-8

Tags: android, json, apache, utf-8, android-volley

In my Android app I need to access a JSON file through the web. Therefore I use volley. It works pretty well, but the special characters are displayed wrong.
The JSON file is stored on my server with apache running. I thought I already solved the problem with editing `httpd.conf` and adding

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .json
```

It shows the special characters the first time I access the file with my app. But the second time the special characters are again unknown.
When I connect to my server and edit and save the file (with some spaces more or less) the first time works again, but not the second.

I tested the app with the file stored in dropbox and it worked like a charm, so the problem has to be my server.

I never worked with apache before so I have no clue where to look and what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it out by myself. It has something to do with the cachecontrol. Because the file didn't change, I somehow didn't get the proper file and the special characters were messed up.

To solve this, I disabled caching in apache by adding:

```
FileETag None

Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
```

into the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file.

To use Header you also have to type

> sudo a2enmod headers

into your terminal.

After that, restart your apache and it now should ignore all caching.